# Socket broadcast doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Hi for some reason I can't execute this line of code on the server (And gladly I want to be able to execute this line of code):

```
 socket.broadcast.emit('server.game.join.team', { user: socket.user, team: data.team, room: data.room });
```

But I can execute this line of code:

```
socket.emit('server.game.join.team').emit('server.game.join.team', { user: socket.user, team: data.team, room: data.room });
```

Here is the full code of what I'm using on the server:

```
joinTeam: function (socket, io, data, callback) {
    if (!data || !data.team || !data.room) return; 

    socket.join(data.team + '-' + data.room);
    console.log('joinTeam');
    socket.broadcast.emit('server.game.join.team', { user: socket.user, team: data.team, room: data.room });
    //socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('server.game.join.team', { user: socket.user, team: data.team, room: data.room });
    //socket.to('server.game.join.team').emit('server.game.join.team', { user: socket.user, team: data.team, room: data.room });
    //socket.emit('server.game.join.team').emit('server.game.join.team', { user: socket.user, team: data.team, room: data.room });
}
```

And on the client I have this piece of code to check when I'm emitting an event from the server:

```
Socket.on('server.game.join.team', function (data) {
   console.log('gameCtrl server.game.join.team');
});
```

I have recorded myself to show that socket broadcast doesn't work for me. Here is the link of the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QML4QE3F90o

But in the in video I had shown that this line of code didn't work me:

```
socket.broadcast.to(data.room).emit('server.game.join.team', { user: socket.user, team: data.team, room: data.room });
```

Instead I should have shown you that this line of code also didn't work for me:

```
socket.broadcast.emit('server.game.join.team', { user: socket.user, team: data.team, room: data.room });
```

So if you want I can record myself again. To prove you that the line of code above also doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
socket.broadcast.emit(...)
```

Sends to every connected socket EXCEPT the one represented by the `socket` variable.  So, if you're watching the client that is the `socket` connection, then you will not see that broadcast message.  Think of a multi-user chat, where one user posts a message and then the server broadcasts that message to all the other users, but not back to the same user that just sent it.

If you want to send to all connected sockets, then you use:

```
io.emit(...);
```

Comment: Hi I had tried to use this code on the server:
io.emit('server.game.join.team', { user: socket.user, team: data.team, room: data.room });

But that doesn't work because weird things happen like when I'm joining the other side of the as user bassie then my name changes to BA. Here is a video what I actually mean link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3AmMyyu65OI